# Build fails automatic checks on CRAN but not on any local checks

Tags: r, devtools, cran, readr

I am trying to submit a new package to CRAN. After submitting, I got a response that it been rejected beacuse it did not pass the automated checks.

Specifically, the error message was as follows for the Windows build.

```
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package required but not available: 'readr'
```

See the log for Windows [here](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/fitzRoy_0.2.0_20191107_051738/Windows/00check.log). It passed all checks for the Debian build [fine](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/fitzRoy_0.2.0_20191107_051738/Debian/00check.log) (side note, I am fixing the NOTES relating to URL's).

The package passes all check on my local machine (Mac OS) as well as on travis-ci and using rhub/devtools to test on Windows. Specifically, I can run the following all without errors.

`devtools::check()`

`devtools::check_win_develop()`

`rhub::check_for_cran()`

Regarding `readr` which seems to be the cause of the issue, it is in the DESCRIPTION file as an Import and seems to be referenced correctly in the various functions. And again, all the above checks pass fine.

Is there some other way to test for CRAN that I'm missing here? I'm hesitant to resubmit without any changes but am not really sure what to change as I can't work out what is going wrong.

For reference, the package is [on github](https://github.com/jimmyday12/fitzRoy).

Comment: Did you install the latest version on your machine?

Comment: It's probably just a random glitch. If it happens again when you resubmit, try contacting the CRAN team.

Comment: maybe its missing in your NAMESPACE file?